# gThumb freezes on start

Tags: 14.04, gthumb

I am not sure if some `.lock` file remained somewhere or it happened after yesterday's system update, but I cannot start gThumb any more.

When I open it it freezes, turns grey and I have to kill it.

Tried uninstalling it (remove and purge), deleting all `gthumb` folders with settings, installing new version... nothing helped.

Anyone has ideas how can I reset gThumb and make it work?

Comment: Which settings folders specifically have you tried deleting? Also, how are you opening gThumb?

Comment: I tried opening in by double-click on an image (default app), but also tried via console. The same freeze. I deleted settings from /home, but only after I got these issues. The deletion did not cause the issue. I deleted 2 folders `gthumb` from `~/.config/gthumb` and `~/.local/share/gthumb`

Answer (score 4):

A tip on http://ask.systutorials.com/715/gthumb-hangs-at-startup-on-fedora helped me: Unmount all iphone mountpoints.

Comment: I had a webdav mount opened.  Gthumb unfroze once I have unmounted it.  Seams that it has problem with remote mounted directories.  This occurred with Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: i can confirm gThumb has problems with offline mount points. i had several Samba shares mounted, and after the remote device got offline i could not open (local) pictures with gThumb. after unmounting all Shares, everything was fine again. Guess this is distribution agnostic, i am using Manjaro Linux..

Comment: i filed a bug report here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gthumb/issues/75